# Insert select - using selected value in ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE

Tags: mysql, select, update, mysql-5.7, insert

In the following query, oversimplified from my actual scenario but close enough:

```
INSERT INTO foo(bar_id, baz)
SELECT
    id,
    5 AS new_baz
FROM
    bar
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE baz=new_baz
```

I get an `Unknown column 'new_baz' in 'field list'` error. However, if I change the last line to contain `baz=bar.id` instead then it all works, so it seems like it's an issue with the fact that `new_baz` is not actually from a column in a table, but a literal value.

How can I use the value of `new_baz` in the last `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` line?

Comment: `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE baz = VALUES(baz)`

Comment: You could use `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE baz = 5` of course but the above syntax is more versatile.

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ Thanks, is that meant to be `VALUES(new_baz)`? I don't see where `new_baz` even comes into it otherwise. Assuming so, that still gives the same error unfortunately.

Comment: See [VALUES() function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_values). *is that meant to be VALUES(new_baz)?* NO.

Comment: The `new_baz` is ignored; the columns are matched by order, not by name.

Comment: None of the answers work

Comment: @ArunSR see my complete answer. What did you try and what error did you get?

Comment: My bad didnt read the doc well. it should be insert statement col name. not select statement. OP should mark that as answer

Answer (score 2):

It should be: `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE baz = VALUES(baz)`

When the query finds a duplicate and the `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` clause is activated, we can use the `VALUES(x)` syntax to get the **values that were to be inserted in the `x` column**. The name used (new_baz) in the select query is irrelevant and can't be used there.

For more details, see MySQL's documentation about the [VALUES()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_values) function.

Complete query:

```
INSERT INTO foo 
   (bar_id, baz)
SELECT
    id, 5 AS new_baz
FROM
    bar
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
    baz = VALUES(baz) ;
```