# Unable to use result of a "subquery in select clause" in a "insert.. select.. on duplicate update" query

Tags: mysql, insert, mysql-8.0

Possible Unanswered Duplicate Question: [Insert select - using selected value in ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/259600/insert-select-using-selected-value-in-on-duplicate-key-update)

I am not able to use a subquery result column in the select clause as a value to update in a `insert into ....(select... ) update on duplicate` query.

Getting  `Error Code: 1054. Unknown column in 'field list'` error.

Attached reduced and simple repro steps.

My original case involves 15 columns and too many complicated `JSON_TABLE`s. I have a work around that repeats the whole subquery again in the update clause, but that doubles the query execution time compared to omitting that column and updating.

```sql
drop table if exists t1;
create table t1 (a int primary key auto_increment, b int);
drop table if exists t2;
create table t2 (c int primary key auto_increment, d int);

insert into t1 (a, b) values (null, 0);
insert into t1 (a, b) values (null, 1);
insert into t1 (a, b) values (null, 2);
insert into t1 (a, b) values (null, 3);
insert into t1 (a, b) values (null, 4);
insert into t1 (a, b) values (null, 5);
insert into t1 (a, b) values (null, 6);
insert into t1 (a, b) values (null, 7);
insert into t1 (a, b) values (null, 8);
insert into t1 (a, b) values (null, 9);

insert into t2 (c, d) values (null, 0);

--doesnt work
insert into t2 (c, d) 
select a, (select 1) as b1 from t1
on duplicate key update
d = t1.b1;

--doesnt work
insert into t2 (c, d) 
select a, (select 1) as b1 from t1
on duplicate key update
d = values(b1);

--work around that takes twice as much time
insert into t2 (c, d) 
select a, (select 1) as b1 from t1
on duplicate key update
d = (select 1);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`(SELECT 1)` can be simplified to just `1`.

```
insert into t2 (c, d) 
        select a, 1 as b1 from t1
    on duplicate key update
    d = values(b1);
```

The `VALUES` clause is 'wrong', change to

```
insert into t2 (c, d) 
        select a, 1 from t1
    on duplicate key update
    d = values(d);
```

Or, in MySQL 8.0:

```
insert into t2 (c, d) 
        select a, 1 from t1
    on duplicate key update
    d = NEW.d
```

If you have a more complex example, you may need to back up to show us what the real problem is.

Answer (score 3):

> ```
> insert into t2 (c, d) 
> select a, (select 1) as b1 from t1
> on duplicate key update
> d = t.b1;
> ```

There are 2 tables in this query: `t2` (in UPDATE clause) and `t1` (in FROM clause). You refer to `t.b1` - but there is no `t` table alias in the query text.

Correct variants:

```
insert into t2 (c, d) 
select a, (select 1) as b1 from t1
on duplicate key update
-- d = t1.b1; -- this should be used when the column is used
d = 1; -- literal is used as a source value, so it may be simply repeated
```

```
insert into t2 (c, d) 
select a, (select 1) as b1 from t1 AS t
on duplicate key update
-- d = t.b1;
d = 1;
```

---

> ```
> insert into t2 (c, d) 
> select a, (select 1) as b1 from t1
> on duplicate key update
> d = values(b1);
> ```

The description of the `VALUES()` explicitly tells:

> In an `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` statement, you can use the `VALUES(col_name)` function in the `UPDATE` clause to refer to column values from the `INSERT` portion of the statement. In other words, `VALUES(col_name)` in the `UPDATE` clause refers to the value of col_name that would be inserted, had no duplicate-key conflict occurred.

I.e. an argument of the function is a name of a column which the value should be inserted into. The query is `insert into t2` - so only the column of the table `t2` can be an argument of `VALUES()`. You use `values(b1)` - but there is no `b1` column in `t2`.

Correct variant:

```
insert into t2 (c, d) 
select a, (select 1) as b1 from t1
on duplicate key update
d = values(d);
```

Comment: Are you sure that this works? Did you test it? `insert into t2 (c, d) 
select a, (select 1) as b1 from t1
on duplicate key update
d = t1.b1;` Since `t1` has no column `b1`, I'd expect it to fail.

Comment: This should work though (enclosing the whole select in a derived table): `insert into t2 (c, d) select * from (select a, (select 1) as b1 from t1) as t on duplicate key update d = t.b1;`

Comment: The `d = values (d)` suggestion looks good.

Comment: The enclosing one works. Thanks. ypercube. Post as answer and I will mark it.

Comment: I think @Akina just meant the correct variant of the question that will throw error that I am facing as per my question. And for that - My bad didnt read the doc well. it should be insert statement col name. not select statement

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ You're right. I miss that the source uses literal value. Fixed.